# Smoke only emits for 1 frame?

Tags: smoke-simulation

The smoke emits for one frame and then all the smoke freezes. My scene consists of just a domain, a gun barrel which also has smoke collision and smoke flow inside the barrel.

Here's the .blend:

[image]

Any ideas to why this is happening? Is it a bug?

Thanks

Comment: working fine on 2.73 but not on 2.74

Comment: @Chebhou does that mean its a bug created in 2.74?

Comment: could be, or some changes in the simulation system